# Other than advertising ID and Android_ID, what other identifiers could an app use from the Android system to identify me?

Tags: accounts

Ignoring information I supply the app (such as my email address or phone number), what other identifiers could an app use to identify a user?

I'm referring to a modern app running on Android 10.

Comment: See [Device Identifiers](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/config/device-identifiers) and [Identifying App Installations](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html) and [Best practices for unique identifiers](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids) and [Remember your user](https://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/identify.html)

Comment: and [What's the best way to uniquely identify Android users?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3960797) and [Generating Device-Specific Serial Number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464881) and [Is there a unique Android device ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/) and [Uniquely Identify an Android Handset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679120) and [How to get unique device hardware id in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16869482/9165920)